React Native TV OS: 'No Bundler URL Present' Error When Running on Apple TV Directly from Xcode
New to React Native and React Native TV OS. When attempting to run my app directly on an Apple TV (Physical Device) from Xcode,use xcode to build/run the projectName.xcworkspace file but I encounter an error saying 'No bundler URL present.' Oddly, the app runs smoothly on the simulator without any hiccups. I've checked localhost:8081/Status and it's functioning properly. Additionally, I've confirmed that my Mac is on the same Wi-Fi network as the Apple TV. Strangely, the app initially worked fine on the Apple TV, but after restarting my MacOS, this issue surfaced. Any insights on how to troubleshoot and resolve this would be greatly appreciated! Iam stuck on this for couple of days now. Full Error:
nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1.1:2] Socket SO_ERROR 61
nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C1.1.2:2] Socket SO_ERROR 61
Connection 1: received failure notification
Connection 1: failed to connect 1:61, reason 1,84,46,74,40,73,70,95,51,615
Connection 1: encountered error(1:61)
Task .<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: 1,84,46,74,40,73,70,95,50,612 [1:61])
Task .<1> finished with error [1,84,46,74,40,73,70,95,50,612] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x3009e81e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: lo0, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask .<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8081/status, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8081/status, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
No bundle URL present.
Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.
void * _Nullable NSMapGet(NSMapTable * _Nonnull, const void * _Nullable): map table argument is NULL
